# How can I make an Import function run without opening the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that uses an IMPORTRANGE query to combine data from multiple other sheets. This combined import sheet is read by Google AppSheet. We have realized that the data AppSheet is reading is always outdated. It only reads the data as of the last time the sheet was manually opened.

I followed the steps in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/fh48gy/google_apps_script_to_trigger_calculation_update/) to try to fix this issue by creating this function: function refresh() {SpreadsheetApp.flush()}. I then set up a timed trigger to activate it once an hour. Logs show the function is running, but the data is still not updating until I manually open the sheet.

This is my first time using Apps Script. Any tips/ideas? Is there a different or better way to have the formulas update without opening the file?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I think flush just completes all pending transactions so it may not necessarily perform an update unless the spreadsheet is opened manually

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for that information. Do you happen to know a way to force an update?

Comment: I stopped using formulas a long time ago so I don't have much knowledge about them any longer.  Personally I think they're a waste of time and the lead to unexplainable spreadsheet functionality.

Comment: According to https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en IMPORTRANGE is recalculated every 30 minutes automatically, perhaps the problem is on the AppSheet side. Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Don't forget to include details about if you are using the iOS or Android mobile apps if you are seeing the same using a web browser.

Comment: Hi @Rubén. Thanks for answering. I believe that the 30 minute recalculation only applies if the sheet is open. We have done lots of testing. Until the sheet is manually opened, no updates are visible in AppSheet, even if several days have passed. However, as soon as the sheet is opened, the data in AppSheet is updated. We are only using AppSheet and Sheets in Windows 10. No mobile apps. I can return later to add a minimal reproducible example. Thanks.

Comment: @JustinThurston : I have given another solution by script if you prefer thsi one

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetApp.flush() only works for the script execution that calls it. If you need to refresh the data results from a formula it's uncertain how exactly the spreadsheet will respond as most of the formula calculations are done on the client side. You could verify this by yourself by using your web browser developer tools.

Anyway, spreadsheet formulas have several caveats so it will not be extrange that at some point you will have to rethink your solution. Assuming that you want to keep using AppSheet:

- Use AppSheet for your front end and some no-code / low-code automation. Keep your app small, if you need many forms / views consider to distribute them among several apps.
- Use Google Sheets only for data storage for your AppSheet app. Please bear in mind that it has 10 million cells limit for the whole spreadsheet, so you might want to delete the unused sheets and delete the unused columns and rows on each sheet.
- You might use Google Apps Script to do the data import and transformation tasks. If you need that something be updated based on actions done on the AppSheet app, you might use an installable change trigger or use webhook from the AppSheet side to and a "simple" web application using Google Apps Script (you could use  GET / POST http requests to trigger some Google Apps Script functions).

Also you might use other programming platforms for the data import / transformation tasks and keep using Google Sheets as your AppSheet database by using the Google Sheets API or other automation tools like Zappier, IFTTT, Integromat among many others.

Answer (score 0):

### solution #1

You can try this solution :

define a checkbox (for instance in A1 in tab Sheet1)

set this script

```
function myFunction() {
  var chk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A1')
  chk.setValue(false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(500);
  chk.setValue(true);
}
```

define a trigger on it

define the formula as follows

```
=if(A1,importrange("1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI","A:Z"),"")
```

[image]

when A1 is unchecked, the result will be empty, then check A1 to fill once again the result as expected

### solution #2

by script, try for instance

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet9')
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1n-rjSYb63Z2jySS3-M0BQ78vu8DTPOjG-SZM4i8IxXI').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues()
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

put a daily triger as needed

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for answering. At first, it seemed like your solution would require me to manually check the box, which would not solve the issue since the goal is an automatic update. However, I think that's not true. It looks like the script will uncheck and recheck the box that populates the query, so that in effect nothing changes, but a recalculation of the formula is forced. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: No, put a daily trigger on the function, and it will run alone.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will give this a try!